# In what geographic area was Moshe put in the Nile?

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu, egypt

The Jews lived in Goshen (near one end of the Nile) but the Pharaoh's palace presumably was elsewhere.

So where was it that Moshe was placed in the Nile?

Answer (score 0):

Ramses II built Pi-Ramses as his capital, which was in the area associated with Goshen: the upper east side of the Nile Delta.

Comment: I saw indeed a picture online stating that it was in this area. In the area of Heliopolis. Near On- אֹ֖ן

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heliopolis_(ancient_Egypt)

Comment: So near where modern day Cairo is.

Comment: A little web search reveals that the Pharaoh of Egypt had more than one palace.  I did not find a palace in Goshen.  Also, I did not find an authoritative source as to the exact location of Goshen, other than it was near current day Cairo.

Comment: What may be the major Palace of Ramses II "Qantir/Pi-Ramesse (House of Ramses) is situated in the Nile-Delta of Egypt, about 120 km northeast of Cairo."
(https://www.artefacts-berlin.de/portfolio-item/the-reconstruction-of-pi-ramesse/ )
(http://www.touregypt.net/featurestories/qantir.htm )

Another Temple Palace of Ramses II was in Abydos which Google Maps shows as 500+ km from Cairo, (https://www.archaeology.org/news/7509-190329-egypt-ramesses-ii-temple )

Comment: Since there was more than one palace, a logical question is: Where would the family (i.e., the daughter) of the Pharaoh live?

Comment: The midrash about Pharoah's daughter's arm extending doesn't say how far it extended. Perhaps it extended a thousand miles.